# javascript array from an entity framework table

Tags: javascript, .net, entity-framework

I would like to generate this array in a JavaScript file

```
var sports = [{ id: 1, value: "Baseball" },
                        { id: 2, value: "Soccer" },
                        { id: 3, value: "Basketball" },
                        { id: 4, value: "Volleyball" },
                        { id: 5, value: "Tennis" },
                        { id: 6, value: "Running" },
                        { id: 7, value: "Swimming" },
                        { id: 8, value: "Tournament"}];
```

I have started with:

```
var sports = db.Sports;
```

But now I am stuck on how to include this in a JavaScript file. Does .net have embedded JavaScript file like Rails do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to just retrieve the data and serialize it into javascript. If those two are the only columns, you can do a straight serialization with JavaScriptSerializer or JSON.NET. If not, you'll need to convert them, maybe something like (using JSON.NET):

```
var x = db.Sports.Select(s => new { id = s.id, value = s.value }).ToArray();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);
```

Once you have this JSON string, you can dump it onto a page however you want, or write it directly to the response.

If you need to know a specific way to do this part, we'd need more details (WebForms or MVC, inside a page or a separate javascript resource, etc.)

**EDIT**:

Adding it to the view once it's in the `ViewBag` is straightforward. Inside your script on the view:

```
var sports = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Sports);
// or if you're not using Razor:
var sports = <%= ViewBag.Sports %>;
```

Since `ViewBag.Sports` is already properly serialized, you don't need to worry about quotation marks or brackets.

Comment: I am doing MVC and this would be inside a page.

Comment: In MVC you're either in a controller or a view - there's not really a concept of a page. Assuming this code is executing in a controller, you can dump that into `ViewBag`, then your view can retrieve it and assign the string contents into a javascript variable. Or you could make it part of your view model.

Comment: Indeed I am in the sports controller. I have added it to the `ViewBag`. I am looking now how to add it to a JavaScript variable.

Comment: Edited answer with javascript.

Comment: This is the HTML generated:

`var sports= System.Collections.Generic.List`1[&lt;&gt;f__AnonymousType4`2[System.Int32,System.String]];`

Comment: You need to assign the serialized string to the ViewBag, not the collection. So in my example, the `json` object was the serialized string, so `ViewBag.Sports = json;`

Comment: Awesome, it works now. One question about the generated string: is there a way to make it put out actual quotes `""` and not the coded ones `&quot;`

Comment: My bad - I forgot that Razor automatically encodes the output - you need `Html.Raw` to write it as-is to the page. See update.